# How to install PHPWhoIs

Tags: centos, ssh, installation, whois

I am trying to install this plugin but haven't found any docs on how to do so.

The project is here: http://www.phpwhois.org/

So far I've figured out I should do `tar -zxvf /plugins/phpwhois-4.2.2.tar.gz`

This unpacked the files to `phpwhois-4.2.2` where I found the read me.

All I get from that is:

```
38  Installation
39  ------------
40  
41  Basically, untar the distribution somewhere outside your server's
42  document root and make sure the directory is listed in 'include_path'
43  in your php.ini file, server configuration or in an .htaccess file.
44  If you want to test it using a web browser just copy example.php ,
45  example.html and whois.icon.png anywhere on your server's document
46  root and try it.
47  
48  phpWhois is not a PHP aplication is a class that can be used in
49  applications. There is no need to make the installation folder
50  accesible to anyone but PHP, nevertheless you can install it inside
51  your server's document root if you like, it will work without
52  problems or security risks.
```

From what I read I need to do `./configure` or something but `configure` doesn't exist in the directory.

Any help?

Comment: Its not a program - there is no 'configure, make, make install' process. These are just PHP files - a class. As long as your code can access it (either via the include_path or by placing it in a directory in your document_root then it can be used. Use it as you would any other PHP class.

Comment: The README expressly says not to install inside document root.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici is that why it says, starting on line 50, "nevertheless you can install it inside your server's document root if you like"? :) ... (Just giving you a hard time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cyberx86 mentioned, this is PHP - you don't have to "build" any source code (using the make / make install process). Do what the readme says:

1. Create a directory outside of our root www directory, maybe somewhere like /usr/local/ or something called "phpwhois". Then untar all of the contents of this tar.gz file in there.
2. "Copy example.php, example.html and whois.icon.png anywhere on your server's document root and try it."
3. I've never worked with this project before, so check example.php to see if you need to specify the path to where the phpwhois files are.

Comment: Is there a way I could do an `include_path` in my server's php.ini file so it would work for all sites?